# Unable to remove negative axis in Scatter Plot using Core-plot2.0

Tags: ios, iphone, core-plot

I have set the plotspace with X and Y Ranges but still I get to see the negative axes. Thoughts anyone?

```
 // Setup scatter plot space
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
    plotSpace.delegate              = self;

    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0] length:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0] length:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
```

Please check the image to see how it looks
[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: The ranges displayed are not what is shown in the code in the question. Is there anywhere else in the app that might change them? Has the user scrolled the graph before taking the screenshot? (That will change the plot ranges, too.)

Comment: Yes i did scroll them. I will disable the scroll but i want both the x and y-axis to start from '0' that's it. Also nothing else in the app would change them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the solution just by setting the visible ranges for both the axis.

```
x.visibleRange   = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:xMin length:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:([xMax doubleValue] - [xMin doubleValue])]];
y.visibleRange   = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:yMin length:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:([yMax doubleValue] - [yMin doubleValue])]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `leftPadding` and `bottomPadding` on the graph and/or plot area frame to leave room for the tick marks and axis labels. If you still want to be able to scroll the graph and leave the axes along the edge, set the `axisConstraints`.

Comment: Will that help me with getting rid of negatives axis?

Comment: Please recheck my question, i have uploaded a new image.

Comment: There's a bad link to the second image; only the markup appears in the question.